# Inject different implementation based on yaml configuration

Tags: python, python-3.x, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Using python package [dependency injector](https://python-dependency-injector.ets-labs.org/index.html), I need to instantiate/inject a different implementation of an interface based on a yaml configuration file.

```
class SomeInterface(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def some_method(self):
        pass

class Impl1(SomeInterface):
    def some_method(self):
        # e.g. file-based implementation

class Impl2(SomeInterface):
    def some_method(self):
        # e.g. service-based implementation
```

I have different yaml configuration files for the different implementations and I want the container to return/inject the appropriate implementation based on the config file. So using dependency injector package, I've created a container:

```
class Container(containers.DeclarativeContainer):

    config = providers.Configuration(strict=True)

    some_implementation = provider.Singleton(Impl1) # <- how to vary this based on config?
```

And I load the yaml config file passed in:

```
container = Container()
container.config.from_yaml(config_yaml_file, required=True)
```

It's not obvious to me how to vary which implementation is injected based on the configuration file passed in to the container.

Comment: Could this be a use for https://python-dependency-injector.ets-labs.org/providers/configuration.html#specifying-the-value-type ? with the `as_` callback mechanism?   Ie you get “Impl1” string from yaml and your callback looks up the class and builds it?  Just guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok never mind, of course it's [in the docs](https://python-dependency-injector.ets-labs.org/providers/selector.html). There are a number of approaches but in my case the Selector provider matches the code I'm refactoring:

```
class Container(containers.DeclarativeContainer):

    config = providers.Configuration()

    selector = providers.Selector(
        config.one_or_another,
        one=providers.Factory(Impl1),
        another=providers.Factory(Impl2),
    )
```